# Make checkbox bydefault false in entity data model in mvc

Tags: entity-framework, checkbox

```
    [Display(Name = "DateOfBirthNone", Order = 435, ResourceType = typeof(Uco.Content.Resources.Models))]
    public virtual bool DateOfBirthNone { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "DateOfDeathNone", Order = 436, ResourceType = typeof(Uco.Content.Resources.Models))]
    public virtual bool DateOfDeathNone { get; set; }
```

these are checkboxes in my UI these are by default TRUE. I want to convert these into by default False. what should i do? Suggest me

Comment: By default C# bool types are false. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8f5xwh7.aspx#sectionToggle0

Can you show the code that sets the checkbox? My guess is it is being set true somewhere.

Comment: thanks 4 ur suggetion..............but problem is resolved now!